# External HDMI Monitor not working with vmlinuz-3.13.0-51-generic

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, updates, multiple-monitors, hdmi

My colleagues and I (four of us) have been using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS since it was released. We are using HP ENVY 17 Laptops with the HDMI port running an external monitor.

Since upgrading to 3.13.0-51 all of the machines no longer detect the HDMI port, and hence the external monitor is no longer displaying anything.

The machines have on-board Intel graphics and also GeForce GT 740M discreet graphics cards.

One of my colleagues has tried to install NVIDIA drivers and he could no longer boot into Unity.

Is there anything else we could try, or should we roll back to 3.13.0-49 ?

UPDATE

Tried installing 3.13.0-52-generic and the problem remains.

Comment: **(1)** Could this be a problem with the Intel driver ? does `zgrep -B 3 xserver-xorg-video-intel /var/log/apt/history.log.*|tail -n 3` gives a recent date ? **(2)**  I have issue too with my external monitor and I  found out in that case I need to completly unplug the monitor from AC power to get it back.

Comment: @solsTiCe - thanks for commenting. **(1)** The output from running your command gives an update for xserver-xorg-video-intel, however if I run `sudo apt-get changelog xserver-xorg-video-intel`, it shows the latest change (2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.6) from 7th April. This problem only occurred today (5th May). **(2)** Removing power does not solve

Comment: It's possible that we are not the only ones having this issue - see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/617277/ubuntu-14-04-on-asus-a46cb-hdmi-not-working)

Comment: Have you tried booting your old kernel from grub 'Advanced' entry ? If not possible if you remove it, you could try to install an older kernel and boot it.

Comment: Tried booting into 3.13.0-49-generic and it doesn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 1):

Hate to report that we've solved the problem by removing the HDMI cable, fully shutting down the computers (we'd only been 'restarting' before) and replacing the HDMI cable once booted up and logged in.

Now we can restart without removing the cable and it works fine.